# How to conditional add and remove `use:` property in Svelte 3?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Is there a way to elegantly and conditionally add and remove `use:` property in Svelte 3?

Example:

```html
<script>
    import {classes} from "./functions.js"

    export let originalClasses
</script>

<button use:classes>Button</button>
```

Is there a way to add or remove `use:classes` if `originalClasses` is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Actions in Svelte can receive a parameter](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action), which you could use to enable or disable the effect.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you have no control over the `classes` function, one way would be to wrap the action with one of your own:

```js
import classes from '....'
function classesWrap(node, useDefault = true) {
  useDefault && classes(node);
  
  return {
    update(useDefault) {
      useDefault && classes(node);
    }
  }
}
```

and then use this action instead: `<div use:classesWrap={originalClasses}>`

This works, kind of, when `originalClasses` is false, it will not set the default ones, and when it is true it will set them.  When it starts as false and turns true it will also apply them (thanks to the `update`) **However** it seems that once an action is attached it cannot be removed again (which is logical as actions are supposed to run when the element gets mounted). This means that turning from *true* to *false* will not change anything, it will keep the default classes.

There are two (really bad) workarounds for this:

1. add some extra code to the update function to remove the classes yourself:

```js
update(useDefault) {
  useDefault && classes(node);
  !useDefault && node.classList.remove(...node.classList);
}
```

(but this removes **all** classes, also those you might have added yourself)

2. a second option is to wrap the element with a `{#key}` block based on `originalClasses` this will force a re-render whenever it changes.

```html
{#key originalClasses}
 <div use:classesWrap={originalClasses}>...</div>
{/key}
```

But this can be **very** expensive if this *div* has a lot of content, maybe for a one line element it might be ok.

(note: you don't need the *update* function anymore)

Of course this assumes that `originalClasses` can and will change, if you are 100% sure it will **never ever** change, just use the wrapper without update or key blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4dfcad7eafd74c8b8f7a35890e3f1581?version=3.36.0)

```js
//functions.js
export default function classes(node,options){
    if(options){
    node.className="myClass";
    }
        console.log(node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got here trying to find out how to conditionally `use` an action. I discovered how to do it, it would look this way using the main example:

```
<script>
    import {classes} from "./functions.js"

    export let originalClasses

    const conditionalAction = originalClasses ? classes : ()=>{};
</script>

<button use:conditionalAction>Button</button>
```

Note that this will only work when the `button` is mounted and not for future value changes. If `originalClasses` was given to the component as `true` (`<MyComponent originalClasses={true} />`), the `classes` action will be used; if `originalClasses` is `false` or not set, the `button` will use no action (noop arrow function: `()=>{}`).