# How can I use use:registerFocus conditionally in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

> Edit: sadly the wrapping approach used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873724/how-to-conditional-add-and-remove-use-property-in-svelte-3) doesn't seem to work for focusing inputs: https://svelte.dev/repl/41625a0612354910aaa59c5a71499977?version=3.50.1

I am using the [`useFocus()` directive from Svelte Navigator](https://openbase.com/js/svelte-navigator/documentation#usefocus). I have an Input component I use for input boxes - I'd like to add a prop `isFocused` so one instance of `Input` can be focused but other instances of `Input` will not be focused.

**How can I use use:registerFocus conditionally in Svelte?**

[Example on Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/41625a0612354910aaa59c5a71499977?version=3.50.1)

Input.svelte:

```
<script>
  import { useFocus } from "svelte-navigator";
  const registerFocus = useFocus();
    
    // How do I makes the component only enable use:registerFocus if isFocused is true?
    export let isFocused 
    export let value
    
    const maybeRegisterFocus = (element, isFocused) => {
        console.log(`Registering focus for '${value}': ${isFocused}`)
        if (isFocused) {
       registerFocus(element);
    }
    return {
      update: (isFocused) => {
                console.log(`Updating for element`, element)
        if (isFocused) {
          registerFocus(element);
        }
        return null;
      },
      destroy: () => {
        return null;
      },
    };
  };
</script>


<input use:maybeRegisterFocus={isFocused} value={value} />
```

App.svelte:

```
<script>
import { Router, Route } from "svelte-navigator";
import Input from "./Input.svelte"
</script>

<Router>
<Route>
    <h1>
        The first input box shoudl be focused.
        <Input isFocused={true} value="First text box should be focused"/>
    <Input isFocused={false} value="Second text box should not be focused"/>

    </h1>
</Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: What is wrong with your approach of just wrapping the action?

Comment: I think it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873724/how-to-conditional-add-and-remove-use-property-in-svelte-3

Comment: @H.B. the wrapping approach doesn't work once I add a second input: https://svelte.dev/repl/41625a0612354910aaa59c5a71499977?version=3.50.1

Comment: @K.Nikita I've attempted to use the wrapping approach mentioned but neither Input focuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the action is the correct approach, the only issue here is that `useFocus` has side effects. Essentially once you call that, you also *have to* use the action.

One way around this would be to create a wrapping component that either sets a context or passes on the action from `useFocus` to its slot.

E.g. using a context:

```html
<Route>
    <FocusContext>
        <h1>
            Hello world
            <Input isFocused={true} value="First text box should be focused"/>
            <Input isFocused={false} value="Second text box should not be focused"/>
        </h1>
    </FocusContext>
</Route>
```

```html
<!-- FocusContext -->
<script context="module">
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';
    export const getFocusContext = () => getContext('FocusContext');
</script>
<script>
    import { useFocus } from "svelte-navigator";
    import { setContext } from 'svelte';

    const focus = useFocus();
    setContext('FocusContext', focus);
</script>
 
<slot />
```

```
<!-- Input.svelte -->
<script>
    import { getFocusContext } from './FocusContext.svelte';

    export let isFocused;
    export let value;
    
    const focus = getFocusContext();
    const maybeFocus = node => isFocused && focus(node);
</script>

<input use:maybeFocus value={value} />
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4dec4f4eb6db475681d9cd39b4f1bf06?version=3.50.1)

Comment: Thanks! I haven't worked with Contexts in Svelte before and trying to understand the docs - is this essentially creating a parent component that, then the parent mounts, will do any focusing?

Comment: Contexts simply make objects available to all components that are descendants of the component where the context was set. Here an additional component was added because `useFocus` cannot be called outside of `Route`. The component just exists to make sure `useFocus` is called only once and to pass it on.